firebase signInWithPopup not retuning auth/account-exists-with-different-credential, it just overwrites
I have a signin page using both email and Google providers, however, I am getting the strange situation where if I register with an email + password, then sign in with Google, signInWithPopup then removes the password/email signin method from the user account.
At no stage do I get any of the errors outlined here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth?hl=en&authuser=0#signinwithpopup
I m expecting auth/account-exists-with-different-credential to be returned, but it is not. See my code from my single sign in buttons here:
import { btnVariants } from "./CustomButton";
import { app } from "../firebase/client";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, TwitterAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { setInitialUserProfile } from "@/utils/helpers/setInitialUserProfile";

export function SingleSignIn({ redirectPath, type }) {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    const methods = [
        {
            label: "Google",
            icon: "/images/icon-google.png",
            id: "google.com"
        },
        {
            label: "Twitter",
            icon: "/images/icon-twitter.png",
            id: "twitter.com"
        },
    ];

    const handleSignIn = async (providerId) => {
        let provider;

        // Getting the correct provider
        if (providerId === 'google.com') {
            provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        } else if (providerId === 'twitter.com') {
            provider = new TwitterAuthProvider();
        }

        provider.addScope('email');

        try {
            const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then(function (result) {
                var user = result.user;
                var credential = result.credential;

                console.log('✅success', user, credential)
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('❌ failed', error)
                var email = error.email;
                var credential = error.credential;
                console.log('❌ failed', email, credential)
                if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
                    auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email).then(function (providers) {
                        console.log('❌ failed, already exists', providers)
                    });
                }
            })


            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error signing in with ${providerId}:`, error);
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="flex flex-col">

                <div className={`flex flex-col gap-2 w-full`}>
                    {methods.map((method, n) => (
                        <div key={n} className="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 items-center">
                            <button
                                onClick={() => handleSignIn(method.id)}
                                className={`${btnVariants({ variant: "outline" })} w-full items-center justify-center`}
                                type="button"
                                disabled={method.disabled}
                            >
                                <div className="gap-2 flex items-center justify-center">
                                    <img src={method.icon} alt="" className="w-4 h-4 mr-2" />
                                    <span className="font-sans capitalize font-medium">
                                        Continue with {method.label}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>

                <div className="relative my-6 md:my-8 xl:my-10">
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center">
                        <span className="w-full border-t border-neutral-200 dark:border-neutral-700"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="relative flex justify-center text-xs">
                        <span className="bg-background px-2 lg:px-4 font-sans font-medium text-foreground">Or</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }




            //     const idToken = await userCredential.user.getIdToken()

            //     // Checking if user profile is setup
            //     const userProfileRef = doc(
            //         db,
            //         "userProfiles",
            //         userCredential.user.uid,
            //     );
            //     const userProfile = await getDoc(userProfileRef);

            //     // If no user profile exists, make one
            //     if (!userProfile.data()) {
            //         // Setting the initial user profile
            //         await setInitialUserProfile(userCredential);
            //     }

            //     // Signing into Firebase
            //     try {
            //         const response = await fetch("/api/auth/signin", {
            //             method: "GET",
            //             headers: {
            //                 Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
            //             },
            //         });

            //         const res = await response.json()
            //         console.log('response', res)

            //         console.log('redirectPath', redirectPath)
            //         //Redirect
            //         if (redirectPath) window.location.assign(redirectPath);
            //         window.location.assign("/dashboard");
            //     } catch (error) {
            //         console.log("❌ Registration error");
            //     }


It sounds like you may be using an email address for which Google is the preferred identity provider, like a @gmail.com address. For such an address of a preferred provider, what you're describing is the expected behavior. See the answer I linked for more on this.

That makes sense. But that is poor UX. If I signed up with a password and try Google, it shouldn’t remove my password. I’ve had another member of the team initially create an account with their password, then on Google. Then tried to sign in on a browser without that Google account signed in with their password and could no longer sign in. Is there no way to disable this feature and keep the password and the Google signin?

Unfortunately not.
